# Why is openpyxl keep corrupting my excel files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to apply styles to cells in my excel files using the openpyxl library. If I try this (using an existing style and modifying it):

```
import openpyxl

wkbk = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
views_sheet = wkbk['Sheet']

cell_ = views_sheet.cell(row=4,column=3)

cell_.style = '20 % - Accent1'
bd = openpyxl.styles.Side(color=openpyxl.styles.colors.Color(theme=29))
cell_.border = openpyxl.styles.Border(left=bd, top=bd, right=bd, bottom=bd)
cell_.font = openpyxl.styles.Font(name='Calibri',size=11,bold=False,italic=False,vertAlign=None,underline='none',strike=False)

wkbk.save('example.xlsx')
```

I open 'example.xlsx' I get that my file is corrupted/needs to be restored. I thought that maybe it isn't possible writing over some existing style, so I created a new named style "highlight" with the associated color:

```
highlight = openpyxl.styles.NamedStyle(name="highlight")
highlight.fill = openpyxl.styles.PatternFill(bgColor=openpyxl.styles.colors.Color(theme=30),fill_type='shaded',patternType='lightGray')
bd = openpyxl.styles.Side(color=openpyxl.styles.colors.Color(theme=29))
highlight.border = openpyxl.styles.Border(left=bd, top=bd, right=bd, bottom=bd)
highlight.font = openpyxl.styles.Font(name='Calibri',size=11,bold=False,italic=False,vertAlign=None,underline='none',strike=False)

wkbk.add_named_style(highlight)

cell_.style = 'highlight'
```

But then I keep getting a ValueError indicating that I need to provide a value for parameter 'patternType' of class 'PatternFill'. This clearly does not makes sense.

Maybe I'm doing this wrong (it's hard to follow the documentation; had to look up older analogous implementations/snippets). Would appreciate some help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is very late, but I had a similar issue where openpyxl was corrupting my .xlsx files when I tried to write a Pandas dataframe to an Excel workbook. The issue turned out to be that the workbook had some other tabs with formulas in certain cells, and for some reason the formulas get corrupted when openpyxl runs. I don't understand why, but the "fix" is to remove the formulas (so, hardcode anything you can).

Comment: Im having this same issue but i need the formulas, do anyone knows a solution for this?

Comment: @Carlost can you write your Pandas dataframe to one sheet with no formulas, then have another sheet which has a formula that points to the dataframe sheet?

Comment: Nope, the file also have diagrams and all get messed up